# python pointer is not changed in recursive function

Tags: python, pointers, recursion, binary-tree

This is the problem that I want to solve. However, I cannot figure out why the pointer of ans is changed in recursion function but is still the same in the main function. Could anyone points out where the problem is?

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-a-corresponding-node-of-a-binary-tree-in-a-clone-of-that-tree/solution/

```
class Solution:
    def getTargetCopy(self, original: TreeNode, cloned: TreeNode, target: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        # the helper dfs function
        def dfs(root):
            if not root: return
            if root.val == target.val:
                ans = root
                return
            dfs(root.left)
            dfs(root.right)
        
        # main function
        ans = TreeNode(0)
        dfs(cloned)
        return ans
```

Also, I have tried changing return ans to return ans.right and it works.
Still don't understand why it works but the upper one cannot work

```
class Solution:
    def getTargetCopy(self, original: TreeNode, cloned: TreeNode, target: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        # the helper dfs function
        def dfs(root):
            if not root: return
            if root.val == target.val:
                ans.right = root
                return
            dfs(root.left)
            dfs(root.right)
        
        # main function
        ans = TreeNode(0)
        dfs(cloned)
        return ans.right
```

Comment: Note that you are returning `None` in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `ans` in the inner function is local to the inner function.  You will need to use a member variable (`self.ans`) or make it a global in both functions.

Comment: but if I return the node as ans.right as below, it works! I don't know the difference between them... 
        # in the helper dfs function: ans.right = root
        # in main function: return ans.right

Comment: If you do `ans.right = x`, that's not creating a new variable.  That's modifying an existing object, so the name search will look in the outer function.  Creating a new binding (as in `ans = root`) has different rules.

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot for your help! I don't know the python mechanism works like this until now.

Answer (score 0):

Compare these three examples:

```py
In [32]: def outer():
    ...:     def inner():
    ...:         val = 3
    ...:         print(f"inner val: {val}")
    ...:     val = 0
    ...:     print(f"outer1 val: {val}")
    ...:     inner()
    ...:     print(f"outer2 val: {val}")
    ...:

In [33]: outer()
outer1 val: 0
inner val: 3
outer2 val: 0
```

```py
In [34]: def outer():
    ...:     val = 0
    ...:     def inner():
    ...:         val = 3
    ...:         print(f"inner val: {val}")
    ...:
    ...:     print(f"outer1 val: {val}")
    ...:     inner()
    ...:     print(f"outer2 val: {val}")
    ...:

In [35]: outer()
outer1 val: 0
inner val: 3
outer2 val: 0
```

```py
In [36]: def outer():
    ...:     def inner():
    ...:         nonlocal val
    ...:         val = 3
    ...:         print(f"inner val: {val}")
    ...:     val = 0
    ...:     print(f"outer1 val: {val}")
    ...:     inner()
    ...:     print(f"outer2 val: {val}")
    ...:

In [37]: outer()
outer1 val: 0
inner val: 3
outer2 val: 3
```

Only the last one works the way you want it to. Python variable scope is local by default, you need to explicitly tell it to look in the enclosing scope via the `nonlocal` declaration, otherwise you are defining a new variable local to the inner function.

See https://www.educative.io/edpresso/the-legb-rule-in-python

So this should work:

```py
class Solution:
    def getTargetCopy(self, original: TreeNode, cloned: TreeNode, target: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        # the helper dfs function
        def dfs(root):
            nonlocal ans
            if not root: return
            if root.val == target.val:
                ans = root
                return
            dfs(root.left)
            dfs(root.right)
        
        # main function
        ans = TreeNode(0)
        dfs(cloned)
        return ans
```

Another example as discussed in the comments:

```py
In [44]: def outer():
    ...:     def inner():
    ...:         val["a"] = 3
    ...:         print(f"inner val: {val}")
    ...:     val = {"a": 1}
    ...:     print(f"outer1 val: {val}")
    ...:     inner()
    ...:     print(f"outer2 val: {val}")
    ...:

In [45]: outer()
outer1 val: {'a': 1}
inner val: {'a': 3}
outer2 val: {'a': 3}
```

Here we can see that `nonlocal` declaration is not needed... for attribute or item access it seems that Python *will* look to the enclosing scope to find the instance.

Comment: Hi Anentropic, thank you for the detailed explanation! I have edited the post, could you take a look because I cannot understand why it works by returning `ans.right`...

Comment: You have found a quirk of the Python variable scoping :) ...accessing an attribute on a var (or key from a dict) convinces Python to try and find the instance in an enclosing scope.  I think the rationale is that the behaviour for bare vars avoids mistake where you accidentally overwrite a non-local value when you meant to just create a local one.  And then I guess it is allowed for attribute/item access because it is not ambiguous, if the instance doesn't exist locally you must have meant the outer one.  But it ends up being confusing all the same!